# How to separate numeric and text in SQL when the whole column is stored as text?

Tags: sql, text, numeric, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column which includes both numeric and text data. Because numeric represents one group and text represents the other group. However, the column is stored as text in SQL. Is there anyway I can separate them into two groups based on this column? Btw, I am using snowflake data warehouse.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions.  For instance, to put the number values first:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (case when column1 rlike '^[0-9]+$' then 1 else 2 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use TRY_TO_NUMERIC() which returns the number value if it is convertable, and a NULL otherwise.  So, for example:

```
create table xx(s string);
insert into xx values('hello_there'), ('1234'), ('look_out'), ('452');

select s, -- original column
       try_to_numeric(s) snum,  -- numeric version of the column
       case when snum IS NULL then s else NULL end sstr -- non-numeric string
from xx;
```

[image: Here are the results]